# How to get time difference between MIN timestamp and MAX timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, max, min

I'm trying to get the MAX & MIN Timestamp for the certain time frame. As you can see here:

[image: Image of data]

I will use mysql or pl/sql

Is it possible to get it?

Example:

```
Black block: 11/2/2022 05:45:28 ~ 11/2/2022 06:02:58
Red block: 13/2/2022 05:34:09 ~ 13/2/2022 06:32:44
Yellow block: 13/2/2022 10:28:06 ~ 13/2/2022 10:40:35
```

Comment: Can you please leave more detail as to what some sample data looks like, what you are receiving, and what you are looking to see?

Comment: `OVER (PARTITION BY EQUIPMENT ORDER BY EQUIPMENT)` - such ORDER BY makes no sense. `CASE WHEN (STATUS_FLAG LIKE 'Y') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS COUNTER` - if `status_flag` cannot be NULL then this can be replaced with single `STATUS_FLAG LIKE 'Y'`.

Comment: Provide sample data as code-formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (10 rows enough, and excess columns may be removed) and desired output for this data.

Comment: I suspect you want a common table expression (CTE) where you'd get the population you're looking for first and then apply your time condition.  As the other comments indicate, it's a little unclear what you're going for and difficult for people to recreate locally to help.

Comment: @YaakovEllis i already attached image of what data that i want

Comment: @IsyrafFikri yes, I see. But it is much easier for folks to be able to use that if you embed the image in the post (add a `!` before the link in your markdown), and explain more explicitly what the different highlighted sections represent.

Comment: @YaakovEllis im sorry but this is my first question in stackoverflow. i need at least 10 reputation to post images

Comment: @YaakovEllis and how your blocks are partitioned??
acc to what creteria you are choosing blocks?

Answer (score 1):

**The question is: Is it possible to get it?**

Sure it is.  I'm done here right Question answered?

Ok as to How... :P

NOTES:

- Assumes each group begins with a Y and ends with the record prior to next Y and that is sorted by count column which has no gaps.

  - if there are gaps, we could assign a row_number() over (partition by X order by ...) as part of an earlier step and use it instead of count
  - Didn't test edge case of Y group without an N.  but I think the min/max will just be the same and it will work out.
- Not a complete solution but does provide a sufficient example to build from. This solves your Grouping problem and obtains the min/max but it doesn't do it using all your columns/data and I don't actually subtract them... but it does give your "Example" results.
- I cheated and simply used #'s instead of actual timestmaps because I'm lazy and didn't want to setup the data.
- Create CTE with sample data
- Create STEP1 CTE which created a column of data which defines each Block/Group based on the next "Y" in your list  I called it "NextMinCount" it would be more aptly named "MyGrouping"
- Then once we have the block/group column
- We use a query to get min/max within each group

SAMPLE DATA: [DEMO DB FIDDLE UK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=37273153849f04fe68594370c94f53af)

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+--------+
| Equipment | Status_Flag | Time_Stamp | counts |
+-----------+-------------+------------+--------+
| EXPCA1Z43 | Y           |       1234 |      0 | <--Begn Grp 4
| EXPCA1Z43 | N           |       1235 |      1 |
| EXPCA1Z43 | N           |       1236 |      2 |
| EXPCA1Z43 | N           |       1237 |      3 |
| EXPCA1Z43 | N           |       1238 |      4 | <--End Grp 4
| EXPCA1Z43 | Y           |       1239 |      5 | <--Begin Grp 7
| EXPCA1Z43 | N           |       1240 |      6 |
| EXPCA1Z43 | N           |       1241 |      7 | <--End Grp 7
| EXPCA1Z43 | Y           |       1242 |      8 | <--Begin Grp 'Last'
| EXPCA1Z43 | N           |       1243 |      9 |
| EXPCA1Z43 | N           |       1244 |     10 |
| EXPCA1Z43 | N           |       1245 |     11 | <--End Grp 'Last'
+-----------+-------------+------------+--------+
```

Assumes the groups begin with a Y and end with row prior to next Y assuming sorted by counts column with no gaps.

```
With CTE AS (SELECT 'EXPCA1Z43' Equipment, 'Y' Status_Flag, 1234 Time_Stamp, 0 counts UNION ALL
             SELECT 'EXPCA1Z43' Equipment, 'N' Status_Flag, 1235 Time_Stamp, 1 counts UNION ALL
             SELECT 'EXPCA1Z43' Equipment, 'N' Status_Flag, 1236 Time_Stamp, 2 counts UNION ALL
             SELECT 'EXPCA1Z43' Equipment, 'N' Status_Flag, 1237 Time_Stamp, 3 counts UNION ALL
             SELECT 'EXPCA1Z43' Equipment, 'N' Status_Flag, 1238 Time_Stamp, 4 counts UNION ALL
             SELECT 'EXPCA1Z43' Equipment, 'Y' Status_Flag, 1239 Time_Stamp, 5 counts UNION ALL
             SELECT 'EXPCA1Z43' Equipment, 'N' Status_Flag, 1240 Time_Stamp, 6 counts UNION ALL
             SELECT 'EXPCA1Z43' Equipment, 'N' Status_Flag, 1241 Time_Stamp, 7 counts UNION ALL
             SELECT 'EXPCA1Z43' Equipment, 'Y' Status_Flag, 1242 Time_Stamp, 8 counts UNION ALL
             SELECT 'EXPCA1Z43' Equipment, 'N' Status_Flag, 1243 Time_Stamp, 9 counts UNION ALL
             SELECT 'EXPCA1Z43' Equipment, 'N' Status_Flag, 1244 Time_Stamp, 10 counts UNION ALL
             SELECT 'EXPCA1Z43' Equipment, 'N' Status_Flag, 1245 Time_Stamp, 11 counts ),
STEP1 as (SELECT A.*, coalesce((SELECT MIN(Counts)-1 
                         FROM CTE B
                        WHERE A.Counts < B.Counts 
                          and B.Status_Flag='Y'),'LASTGROUP') NextMinCount
FROM CTE A)


SELECT nextMincount, Min(Time_Stamp) MinForGroup, max(Time_Stamp) maxForGroup  
FROM STEP1
GROUP BY nextMinCount
```

Giving us:

The heart of the above which defines the grouping is this inline select:

```
coalesce((SELECT MIN(Counts)-1 
                             FROM CTE B
                            WHERE A.Counts < B.Counts 
                              and B.Status_Flag='Y'),'LASTGROUP')
```

It simply identifies the lowest "Count" that is a "Y" that is greater than the current count .  Thus defining the range for the group.  We then subtract 1 to get the row prior to the Y.  we use the coalesce to handle the last grouping which would not have a next Y value and would otherwise be NULL name; and we get the Step1 Results depicted for STEP 1

STEP 1 gives us:

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+--------+--------------+
| Equipment | Status_Flag | Time_Stamp | counts | NextMinCount | <--Should have called 
+-----------+-------------+------------+--------+--------------+    This MyGrouping
| EXPCA1Z43 | Y           |       1234 |      0 | 4            |
| EXPCA1Z43 | N           |       1235 |      1 | 4            |
| EXPCA1Z43 | N           |       1236 |      2 | 4            |
| EXPCA1Z43 | N           |       1237 |      3 | 4            |
| EXPCA1Z43 | N           |       1238 |      4 | 4            |
| EXPCA1Z43 | Y           |       1239 |      5 | 7            |
| EXPCA1Z43 | N           |       1240 |      6 | 7            |
| EXPCA1Z43 | N           |       1241 |      7 | 7            |
| EXPCA1Z43 | Y           |       1242 |      8 | LASTGROUP    |
| EXPCA1Z43 | N           |       1243 |      9 | LASTGROUP    |
| EXPCA1Z43 | N           |       1244 |     10 | LASTGROUP    |
| EXPCA1Z43 | N           |       1245 |     11 | LASTGROUP    |
+-----------+-------------+------------+--------+--------------+
```

The final query gives us

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| nextMincount | MinForGroup | maxForGroup |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| 4            |        1234 |        1238 |
| 7            |        1239 |        1241 |
| LASTGROUP    |        1242 |        1245 |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

WHERE the nextMinCount equates to your blocks of data as the Step1 results show.

- 4 = your black
- 7 = your red
- LAST GROUP = your yellow

Which, I believe, is what you're after.

Comment: Ok, revisions complete sorry about all the updates.  I still want to correct a column name but it's not worth the effort as the example works.  We could likely simplify this avoid some of the CTE or use a sub query... but I liked the CTE sequence top down.

Comment: Yeah I updated it again to handle the edge case of Y w/o an N.  No code change but I wanted to comment about it just in case

Comment: so which part did it separated? I mean if the program saw the first Y then it will increase the number.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Essentially his relies on two aspects: 1)  "Y" denotes a new group is needed.  2)  count defines the order in which the records are sequenced and is linear in growth (always +1 no gaps)  These are two major assumptions.  So  the inline select simply finds the next "Y" for a given count# and subtracts 1 from it to get the last "N" record in the group.  All records prior to the next "Y" get the last N record's count as it's group.   Since the last group will have no next "Y" I assign "LastGroup" to it using coalesce since the max will be <NULL>.

Comment: @IsyrafFikri  abandonded?